# Will a Wi-Fi Access point affect maximum addresses configured via port-security

Tags: cisco-catalyst, access-point, port-security

I want to configure port-security on a c2960 cisco switch to allow maximum of 10 MAC addresses per port. However two of the switch ports will be connected to a Wi-Fi access point for wireless users. If more than 9 clients connect to the WiFi access point will a security violation occur?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That depends on how the access point is configured. If it's configured as a router you'll only see one address of the access point itself, but if it's configured as a bridge between the wireless and the wired network, you'll see a MAC address for every connected client.

Comment: its configured as an access point to the wired network not a router.

Comment: @Manny264, as a bridge, the WAP will look as if you had connected another switch to your switch port, and the switch port will see all the MAC addresses of every Wi-Fi client which has traffic come through the port. Bridges, like switches or WAPs, do not alter the MAC addresses in the frames. So, yes, a security violation will occur in you scenario.